# Not able to drop a database in Toad

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using Toad 8.5.0.50, Oracle 10.2.

I created a database and trying to drop it but getting an error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I have tried different syntaxes like adding removing of ';' or '/' but no difference.

```
DROP DATABASE sch_DB1;
```

Comment: I think you mean you want to drop a "schema" (ie, a "user" and the objects it owns). In Oracle terminology, a "database" is the entire instance you're running in, so you can't drop it. If so, you probably want `DROP USER sch_DB1 CASCADE;` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9008.htm#SQLRF01811

Comment: It is the answer. Thanks!